# Enviar imagen en bytes a una api

Tags: vb.net, postman

Tengo una api para a la cual debo enviarle una imagen en bytes, pero por alguna razon a la api le llega la variable en nulo. que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

esto es lo que le envio a travez de postman, la imagen es la unica variable que no llega correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu variable vac_imagen es typo byte[] ? si es asi, cuando envias datos en el cuerpo de una peticion, estos realmente se envian como string, y es el model binder el que se encarga de interpretarlos y 'castearlos', a lo que voy es que, lo mas probable es que  vac_imagen en tu peticion es solo un string, y lo trata como tal, como no hace match, entonces no lo inicializa en tu modelo, quedando Null. las imagenes deberian de agregarse como file en la peticion y recivirlos en el Request.Files(en caso de ser MVC) en tu metodo.

Comment: y como deberia enviar la imagen en el json? en realidad la imagen que se va enviar es de un fotografia toma en unos momentos antes de ejecutar la funcion del controlador, es decir de la aplicacion, se toma una foto y luego se la envia junto con los parametros a la api, el controlador debe recibir tanto los parametros, que te muestro en la primera imagen, como la foto para luego almacenarlos en la base de datos

Comment: si necesitas enviarlo por ese medio, puedes enviarlo en una variable tipo string, ya sea la misma u otra dentro del modelo, y una vez en el back, conviertes ese string a un array bytes[] y lo asignas a la variable de tu modelo.

Comment: si pero despues necesito transformar el arreglo en una imagen. Para ello intente usar  "Dim imagenenbytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagenremito)" siendo imagenremito el string que recibe la imagen, luego uso esto  "Dim Imagenreducida As Image = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)" pero al intentar convertirlo en imagen me dice "El parametro no es valido" "'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.ArgumentException' al tipo 'Entidades.Excepcion"

Comment: como puedo hace eso?

Comment: perimero te recomiento que cheques si lo que tienes si es un array de bytes o un base64 , porque para mi parece mas un base64, si tu string termina con un = o puedes calarlo aqui https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter si lo decodifica, es base64. si es asi entonces la idea es de base64 a imagen.